# Understanding Python IndentationError and SyntaxError

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to understand why Python 3.5.1 sometimes throws an `IndentationError` and sometimes a `SyntaxError`, when I'd expect it to throw an `IndentationError` in both cases. For example:

1)

```
>>> if True:
...     pass
...             else:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    else:
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

2)

```
>>> if True:
...     pass
...     else:
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `IndentationError` is because that line was indented more than it should have been. `pass` doesn't require the next line to be indented.

The `SyntaxError` is because, although the line with the `else` statement could theoretically be appropriately indented if it had some other statement like `pass` or `while`, the interpreter couldn't find a necessary preceding statement (`if`, `elif`, `while`, `for`, or `except`) at that indentation level.